# Is there a skippable, countable generator for unique permutations up to some symmetry?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Is there a good algorithm for generating all and only the unique permutations of a finite set respecting some kind of symmetry? For example, in Klondike solitaire, the two black suits are interchangeable, the two red suits are interchangeable, and the black suits are interchangeable with the red suits. This results in 4 symmetries, but from a unique game perspective we only need to generate one representative. Ideally this generator would be countable (identify how many permutations there are), and skippable (go to the Nth permutation without generating intermediary permutations)?

Comment: Can you formalize what you mean by "some kind of symmetry"?

Comment: Is that not the same as all suits are interchangeable?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: To formalize 'some kind of symmetry' I mean that we can transpose some subset of elements with another subset of elements of equal size and get a result that we can afford to ignore.

For example, imagine in the space of permutations of { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, we might for some reason view the odd numbers as interchangeable with the even numbers one greater than themselves, but only if they are fully swapped, so e.g. we could think of { 1, 2, 3, 4 } ~ { 2, 1, 4, 3},

Comment: @Paparazzi: it is not the same as all suits are interchangeable, which would allow e.g. {Clubs -> Hearts, Spades->Spades, Hearts->Diamonds, Diamonds->Clubs}, which would be a different game. However, I'm looking for a technique that would allow me to encode that condition as well.

Comment: Just because I don't understand does not mean it is wrong.  Cheers

Comment: So an alternative phrasing would be that you want to take as input a number $n$ (52 in the example), a suitable representation of a permutation group $G$ which is a subgroup of the symmetric group on $n$ elements $S_n$ (which in the example would be a group isomorphic to the dihedral group of 8 elements), and an index $0 \le i < \frac{n!}{|G|}$; output would be an element of the quotient group $S_n / G$, such that for each $i$ a distinct element is given?